# How to zoom in on an element when scraping an interactive map?

Tags: python, selenium, interactive

The code below is intended to be used to scan the whole of Spain grabbing information from the blue clickable dots (which only become visible in the dark part of the zoom). So if you run the code below it will try to click on the cluster of blue dots but fail because they are all on top of each other and too close together.

Therefore I was wondering it was possible to zoom in on the cluster of blue dots so they all separate from each other, click on all the dots, zoom out again and continue scanning.

```
chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chrome_options.add_argument("--incognito")
chrome_options.add_argument("--start-maximized")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options)

codes = []
driver.get('https://geoportal.minetur.gob.es/VCTEL/vcne.do')

for x in range(2):
    driver.find_element_by_xpath('//* [@id="OpenLayers.Control.PanZoomBar_59_zoomin"]').click()

for x in range(4):
    time.sleep(1)
    driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="OpenLayers.Control.PanZoomBar_59_panup"]').click()

for x in range(3):
     time.sleep(1)
     driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="OpenLayers.Control.PanZoomBar_59_panright"]').click()

for x in range(2):
    driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="OpenLayers.Control.PanZoomBar_59_zoomin"]').click()

for x in range(2):
    time.sleep(1)
    driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="OpenLayers.Control.PanZoomBar_59_pandown"]').click()

for x in range(9):
     driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="OpenLayers.Control.PanZoomBar_59_zoomin"]').click()

for x in range(60000):
    for x in range(273000):
        time.sleep(2)
        towers = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("div#map image[id*='OpenLayers.Geometry']")
        for tower in towers:
            tower.click()
            codes.append(driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="divDatosFeatureInfo"]/table/tbody/tr[3]/td/div/p').text)
        for x in range(14):
            time.sleep(1)
            driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="OpenLayers.Control.PanZoomBar_59_panright"]').click()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Javascript to click on the blue dots, by this way the dots will be clicked though they are overlapped. Here is the sample.

```
#replace "tower.click()" with below line
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();",tower);
```

I might have to dig through to find way to zoom and scroll all Spain map.

Comment: This error jumps when I run it: 'javascript error: arguments[0].click is not a function'

Comment: Did you missed `()` after click?